# How do I get a JSON response after put/post from MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a jquery routine that calls an MVC action which will do a PUT/POST to an API url. The call from jQuery is fine and works as well as the call to the API using C#. A response is received from the API in JSON format when checked via Firebug/Fiddler.

How do i get that response to be sent back to the calling jQuery?

My C# code is:

```
 public string callAPIPut(string ApiUrl, string JsonString)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(JsonString);

        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
        request.ContentLength = JsonString.Length;

        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, JsonString.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        return ""; // How do I return the JSON response from the API?
    }
```

When doing a GET i could use something like the following to get the response back to the calling jQuery:

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   serviceResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
return serviceResponse;
```

I dont know how to return the response when doing a Put/Post?

Comment: Or is you're question about making a call from jQuery?

Comment: It is getting called from jQuery but that part is fine. The question is to do with the response from C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CallAPIPut(string ApiUrl, string JsonString)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonString);
        byte[] result = client.UploadData(ApiUrl, "PUT", data);
        return Content(Encoding.Default.GetString(result), "application/json");
    }
}
```

or make it more intelligently, by wrapping in a custom and reusable action result to avoid cluttering your controller with infrastructure plumbing:

```
public class ApiResult : ActionResult
{
    public ApiResult(string apiUrl, string jsonData)
        : this(apiUrl, jsonData, "PUT")
    {
    }

    public ApiResult(string apiUrl, string jsonData, string method)
    {
        ApiUrl = apiUrl;
        JsonData = jsonData;
        Method = method;
    }


    public string ApiUrl { get; private set; }
    public string JsonData { get; private set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var contentType = "application/json";
        response.ContentType = contentType;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = contentType;
            byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonData);
            byte[] result = client.UploadData(ApiUrl, Method, data);
            response.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(result));
        }
    }
}
```

and now your controller action simply becomes:

```
public ActionResult CallAPIPut(string apiUrl, string jsonString)
{
    return new ApiResult(apiUrl, jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Darin, I have got your initial code to work, have been trying the second, wrapped version but I get an empty JsonData string in the following line: byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonData);

Comment: When you put a breakpoint inside your controller action, is the `jsonString` variable that you are passing to the `ApiResult` constructor being initialized? What happens when you step through the code? At which point is the value being lost?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 newStream.Write(data, 0, JsonString.Length);
 newStream.Close();
```

You're posting JSON to the server. To get JSON you need to post/put and use the ResponseStream to read the data the server returned.

A sample:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request for the URL. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
              "http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams and the response.
            reader.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx

**Edit:** You would return the responseFromServer and consume that in you're Javascript callback.

Comment: How would I incorporate that into the put/post process? That's what I can't figure out?

Comment: Sascha, how would I get my JSON data parameter in there which includes my data to be posted to the server?